# how to update colomn on condition in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

my table Muster contain following data

[image]

And final output I want is

[image]

How to query database to get required output

Comment: What's the difference between the two pictures?

Comment: @Andomar: the order by status

Comment: @Closevoters: This question is pretty clear, if a bit simple!

Comment: @Andomar I want to update my previous table to next table using update command

Comment: SQL tables are unordered sets.  Both tables you show are identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having 4 identical names is confusing, Not 100 % sure what you mean, but if you want to update the current table with opposite values, this is how to do it. Status will remain the same if it has different values.

```
UPDATE Muster
SET status = CASE status WHEN 'present' THEN 'absent'
                         WHEN 'absent' THEN 'present'
                         ELSE status END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * From Muster order by Status
```

hope this will help you.